# Deploying ESB analytics car in DAS

Tags: wso2, wso2-das, wso2-esb

We're evaluating a few WSO2 products for a solution. As part of the requirement we need to deploy the WSO2 analytics car file in DAS(preferably version 3.1.0). When we deploy the car it fails due to an incompatibility in the **EsbAnalytics-ExecutionPlan-statistic** execution plan file. A closer look inside the file shows that it refers to a custom stream function extension called **esbAnalytics**, this file is not available inside the car file or in the usual locations such as lib and dropins.

Can some one please share the steps to make the analytics car work in DAS?

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to use ESB analytics features in DAS, you need to install its features first. The ESB analytics extension comes with those features.

Refer to the documentation[1] for the instructions on installing ESB analytics features on DAS 3.1.0.

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/DAS310/Working+with+Product+Specific+Analytics+Profiles#618096e7e77848b3abcc5785000d53cc